# How to create a HTML Server that multiple mobile phones can connect to directly on a Raspberry Pi Pico W?

Tags: web-server, pi-pico-w

Raspberry Pi Pico W can act as a webserver but it needs to first connect to a wifi router. How to make it so that multiple mobile phones can connect to it directly without the need for a router and serve a html file when users visit 10.0.0.1 in the browser

Comment: No router? How do you expect the mobile phones to see the pico then?

Comment: You might possibly want a zero instead.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen You expect them to see the Pico the same way they would see a router -- or access point, the difference between which is the former forwards traffic back and forth between the WLAN it manages and an external network via a second inet interface, whereas the latter only connects and manages a WLAN.  Access point tech is also used to implement things like what the OP is talking about, devices you can connect to without a router/AP in the middle.  All kinds of IoT devices use this for initial setup so you can provide them with a password to get on your LAN proper.

Comment: ...Which a quick online search reveals that the wifi chip on the Pico does have an access point mode hence could be used to do what's required here.  Search was for "pi pico w access point".  I did not read anything beyond the start of [this thread](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=336901) where an issue seems to be that there's no WPA implementation, ie., it would be an unencrypted open network.  So at a minimum you should be able to use that.

Comment: @goldilocks yes.  The point is that OP is not aware that the software needed for this is more than what may be available for such a small device.

Comment: But it clearly *is* available unless that forum thread I linked is fake (and various other pages a quick search and scan turned up).   The additional software required to use a system that's already capable of connecting to a WLAN using DHCP as an AP w/ DHCP server is not, I think, that volumous.   You can do this with Arduinos and ESPs.  Pretty sure I have light bulbs that do this...

Comment: look at setting up an `active portal` ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Raspberry+Pi+Pico+W+captive+portal&ia=web

Comment: @goldilocks is was an attempt at a rhetorical question to make OP think about what parts are needed

Comment: @goldilocks Thank you, I got it to work already. However, the memory is too small and can't host a large HTML file. Do you guys know if the problem is data storage (which I could expand) or is it RAM (which I can't expand)?

Answer (score 0):

First install RaspAP (Access Point)The easiest, full-featured wireless router setup for Rapberry pi devices.
Second setup your web server.
Third let all your guest connect to your raspberry router as clients.
Voila! Serve your html files, doc, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can set-up Raspberry Pi Pico W as a HTML webserver with no internet. Just follow the instructions in https://microcontrollerslab.com/raspberry-pi-pico-w-soft-access-point-web-server-example/

```
try:
 import usocket as socket        #importing socket
except:
 import socket
import network            #importing network
import gc
gc.collect()
ssid = 'RPI_PICO_AP'                  #Set access point name 
password = '12345678'      #Set your access point password


ap = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
ap.config(essid=ssid, password=password)
ap.active(True)            #activating

while ap.active() == False:
  pass
print('Connection is successful')
print(ap.ifconfig())
def web_page():
  html = """<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head>
  <body><h1>Welcome to microcontrollerslab!</h1></body></html>"""
  return html
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)   #creating socket object
s.bind(('', 80))
s.listen(5)
while True:
  conn, addr = s.accept()
  print('Got a connection from %s' % str(addr))
  request = conn.recv(1024)
  print('Content = %s' % str(request))
  response = web_page()
  conn.send(response)
  conn.close()
```

Now, my problem is that the Raspberry Pi Pico W runs out of memory due. I'd like to know whether it is RAM or Storage as the latter could be expanded but the former can't. The HTML file could be uploaded into the Raspberry Pi but once you run it it says MemoryError: memory allocation failed, allocating ### bytes